# Функциональное тестирование добавления файла

Tags: php, тестирование, codeception, функциональное-тестирование

На сайте в форме добавления товара можно прикрепить к нему изображение как файл. Скажите, каким образом я могу протестировать это функционально? Для тестов использую Codeception.

Comment: вы сформулировали вопрос так, что он подразумевает лишь бинарный ответ «да/нет». скорее всего, вам такой ответ не нужен. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать подходящий вам ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, нашел ответ на свой вопрос. В Codeception нужно использовать метод attachFile, который прикрепляет указанный файл (файл должен содержаться в папке tests/_data) к полю.